# How can mereology be applied to the substantivalism and relationism spacetime discussion?

Tags: reference-request, history, internet

I've just began to try to understand mereology through this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1350094730) with rather great difficulty. As i've dredged through it i've begun to wonder how it is that mereology could influence my favorite philosophical discussion of spacetime substantivalism vs. relationism. What would mereology have to say on this specific discussion and or each position individually? I'm especially interested in how it is that mereology influences interpretations of general or special relativity. I acknowledge the stanford encyclopedia [article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/location-mereology/) but hope for other accessible resources on mereology affecting this well-worn discussion. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific than "what would mereology have to say"? The SEP article already lists 9 references on relativistic mereology near the end, two of which are books, mostly centered on persistence, fusion and multilocation. [Balashov's Relativistic Parts and Places](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-05356-1_2) is a brief survey. In what context did your interest come up? What specific issue are you hoping to apply this to, and to what end?

Comment: Would you happen to know anything on mereological atoms and its relation to discrete spacetimes?

Comment: Does not strike me as concerning relativity so much as quantum gravity, try [Priority Monism Beyond Spacetime by Le Bihan](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/14192/)  and [The curious case of spacetime emergence by Baron](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11098-019-01306-z).

Comment: Somewhat over the top of my head but thank you John Forkosh for this link to quantum gravity. Much appreciated as well conifold.

Comment: Rather intriguing!

Comment: What do you mean by more fundamental "events"?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the issue of monism and special and general relativity, any useful answer to this question requires mastery of the mathematics that underlies both SR and GR. It also requires a compelling mechanistic connection be made between that math and monism in general.

Absent either of these, the idea of tying monism to relativity or otherwise relating them is (to be blunt) a fool's errand.

Should you have any doubts about this, I would recommend that you try posting this on the physics stack exchange and seeing how the larger physics community responds to it.